# ID from parents parent adjacent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the ID of the "parents parent adjacent" element. I've come so far that I can select the element that contains the ID. Now I just need to output the ID.

---

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/ztuttzuL/2/)**

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var a = $('.function').closest('li').find('a:first').attr('id');
    console.log(a);
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="get-this-ID-1">
            Link 1.
        </a>
        <div>
            <div class="function">
                Function 1 here.
            </div>
            <a>Link2 1.</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="get-this-ID-2">
            Link 2.
        </a>
        <div>
            <div class="function">
                Function 2 here.
            </div>
            <a>Link2 2.</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="get-this-ID-3">
            Link 3.
        </a>
        <div>
            <div class="function">
                Function 3 here.
            </div>
            <a>Link2 3.</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: looks like its working. I dont understand what you are not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The issue is `attr` returns value of the first element in the collection. You should iterate through the collection and get the ID of each element individually.

Here is an example using `map` method for generating an array of IDs:

```
var a = $('.function').closest('li').find('a:first').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

You could also use the `:has` selector:

```
$('li:has(.function)').children('a').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it: use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**

```
var a = $('.function').map(function () {
    return $(this).closest("li").find(" > a")[0].id;

}).get();
```

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztuttzuL/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing from `first` to `first-child`:

```
$(function () {
    var a = $('.function').closest('li').find('a:first-child').attr('id');
    console.log(a);
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztuttzuL/3/**